# dissecting lists returned from EF5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a webpage which displays stock price data for the company. I am trying to add additional functionality such as moving averages to the chart. I bind the data to the chart as follows.

```
 Dim stockprices = From c In ctx.stockprices_daily Select New With {c.date, c.high, c.low, c.open, c.last}
chtStockChart.DataSource = stockprices.ToList()
```

The prices in the database are decimal types, the date, well, a date type

Can I use a for each to create a list of just date and last from the returned list rather than requery for those two items? What type of list is generated from the .ToList() on the returned object from EF? I can build the data series for the moving average but I'm stuck on what type of list to use ort even if I should be using that at all or some other data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What type of list is generated from the .ToList()

It generates an `IQueryable` of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) with properties `date`, `high` etc.

> Can I use a for each to create a list of just date and last

You can re-query `stockprices` by e.g.

```
Dim movingAvg = From m In stockprices Select New With { m.date, m.last }
chtStockChart.DataSource = movingAvg.ToList()
```

Which creates a new `IQueryable` of another anonymous type. You will even notice that only one query is executed against the database with only these two fields in the `Select`, because the execution of `chtStockChart` is deferred until the `ToList()`.

Comment: Thank you, learn something new everyday. It didn't dawn on me that you could query for a subset of a base query